# Import Mapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the import path for the Javascript as I would write.

```
import { Button, H1, Text } from "../../../../components/atoms";
```

This is the import state for the Source Code that I'm looking at.

```
import { Button, H1, Text } from "/components/atoms";
```

How do you set up mapping in javascript so that the second import statement can work? I assume I'm missing code somewhere that allows for this kind of imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the docs, you start by creating a jsconfig.json file in your root with these characters and symbols in it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This is because you are using the Create-React-App

Comment: "*This is because you are using the Create-React-App*" I'm not. Your question is tagged just JavaScript, so I expected a solution that is not only for one tool.